# Connected Diagrams

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, partition-function, graph-theory

The generating functional for the connected part of the Green functions is defined 
as

$$iW[j] = \log Z[j].$$

From this the four-point connected Green's function is then given by
$G_c(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)^{(4)}=G^{(4)}(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)-G_c^{(2)}(x_1,x_2)G_c^{(2)}(x_3,x_4)-G_c^{(2)}(x_1,x_3)G_c^{(2)}(x_2,x_4)-G_c^{(2)}(x_1,x_4)G_c^{(2)}(x_2,x_3) \tag 1$

where superscript means functional derivative $W[j]$ in respect to $j$ that is

$$G_c^{(i)}=\frac{\delta }{\delta j_1...\delta j_1}W[j]$$

and

$$G^{(i)}=\frac{\delta }{\delta j_1...\delta j_1}Z[j].$$

From equation $(1)$ we can see that the connected part of   $G^{(4)}(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$  is contained in $G_c(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)^{(4)}$
but how can we prove that $G_c(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)^{(4)}$ does contain only connected parts?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107049/2451 ,  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/129080/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/324252/2451 and links therein.

Comment: It seems that your question has nothing to do with 4 point functions and really you're asking how do we know that W only generates connected components. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Just a remark: there is no "i" in the equation relating W to the logarithm of Z.