# Connected diagrams and Keldysh

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, greens-functions, correlation-functions, s-matrix-theory

I have seen that:

In the ground state ($T = 0$) formulation of the Green’s function written in terms of operators
in the interaction picture, the Green’s function reads:

$$G(r,t;r',t') = -i\frac{\langle T[\Psi(r,t)\Psi^{*}(r',t')S(+\infty,-\infty)]\rangle}{S(+\infty,-\infty)}.$$

One then finds that the denominator $S(+\infty, −\infty)$ i cancels the contribution of disconnected
diagrams so that:

$$G(r,t;r',t') = -i\langle T[\Psi(r,t)\Psi^{*}(r',t')S(+\infty, −\infty)]\rangle_{\rm connected}.$$

In Keyldysh formalism, the Keldysh Green function reads:
$$G^{i,i'}(r,t;r',t') = -i\langle T_{k}[\Psi(r,t_{i})\Psi^{*}(r',t'_{i'})S_{k}(+\infty, −\infty)]\rangle_{\rm connected}.$$

$T_{k}$ is the time ordering on a Keldysh countour. The Keldysh contour goes from $−\infty$ to $+\infty$ (+
time label) and back from $+\infty$ to $-\infty$ (− time label).

[image]

This expression contains connected and disconnected diagram but why in practice only the connected diagram need to be included in the series?

Comment: Please avoid writing your title in capslocks only since this is usually associated with shouting, thus being perceived as rude. Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107049/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/324252/2451 and links therein.