# Free Energy vs. Partition Function in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, feynman-diagrams, path-integral, partition-function

The partition function of QFT is defined as

$$Z=\int\mathcal{D}\varphi e^{iS[\varphi]}.$$

Now, it is a general fact that this formal path integral can be computed perturbatively as (sketchy)

$$Z=\sum_{\Gamma}\frac{\lambda^{V}}{\mathrm{sym}(\Gamma)}\mathcal{A}_{\Gamma}.$$

where the sum is over all Feynman amplitudes of closed (=vacuum) Feynman graphs and where $\lambda$ denotes the coupling. This equality is obtained by perturbing around the coupling $\lambda$ and computing Gaussian integrals, i.e.

$$Z=\int\mathcal{D}\varphi e^{iS[\varphi]}=\int\mathcal{D}\varphi e^{iS_{\mathrm{kin}}[\varphi]}\bigg (\sum_{k}\frac{1}{k!}\bigg[i\int\,\mathrm{d}^{4}x\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{int}}\bigg ]^{k}\bigg )=\\\sum_{k}\int\,\mathrm{d}^{4}z_{1}\dots\mathrm{d}^{4}z_{k}\bigg [\text{apply propagator pairwise to fields }\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{int}}(\varphi(z_{k}))\dots\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{int}}(\varphi(z_{1}))\bigg ]=\sum_{\Gamma}\frac{\lambda^{V}}{\mathrm{sym}(\Gamma)}\mathcal{A}_{\Gamma}.$$

Now, in many text i have seen the claim that the last equality is only true for the free energy, i.e. the claim that

$$F=-i\cdot\mathrm{ln}(Z)=\sum_{\Gamma}\frac{\lambda^{V}}{\mathrm{sym}(\Gamma)}\mathcal{A}_{\Gamma}.$$

I am confused, which formula is correct? The formula for $Z$ or for $F$?

Comment: Could you provide a reference for this claim? My immediate guess is that there is an implicit difference: $Z$ is given by the sum over all diagrams while $F$ is given by the sum over all *connected* diagrams

Comment: I can provide references, but I do not know if this makes sense. The point is that I wrote my question in a more general fashion, such that it is understanable from a more general context. However, the question arises from some special quantum gravity models, like tensor models and GFTs. But if you want, the second claim of the free energy is for example contained in https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.4812 ...

Comment: But even if this is true that the second formula is only for connected diagrams, I can't see why this follows just by putting a logarithm in front...

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107049/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/324252/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Thanks @Qmechanic! Thats indeed very helpful :-)